# Parody names of SF writers in Damon Knight story

Tags: character-identification, authors, damon-knight

The *Infinity* magazine of February 1956 contains the short story ["A Likely Story" by Damon Knight](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/67364). The setup is a meeting of "The Medusa Club", ". . . loosely speaking, an association for professional science fiction writers."

Many of the names of attendees at the meeting are clear parodies of names of SF authors, but I can't identify most of them. Some may, of course, just be funny names. Below are the names, and my guesses for those that I have an idea about. Who are the others?

- Preacher Flatt —
  Fletcher Pratt
- Ray Alvarez
- Rod Pfehl (the P is silent, as in Psmith)
- Tom Q. Jones went by in a hurry, carrying a big camera.
- Punchy Carrol, nut-brown in a red dress
- Duchamp biting his pipe
- Leigh MacKean with her pale protoNordic face —
  Leigh Brackett?
- the ubiquitous fan, Harry You-Know, the one with the glasses and all that hair
- Dorrance Canning, an old idol of mine; he wrote the "Woman Who Slept" series and other gorgeous stuff —
  far-fetched, possibly a joke on (from a history of Campbell Soup) "In 1897, John T. Dorrance . . . developed a commercially viable method for condensing soup"
- Art Greymbergen, my favorite publisher
- Bill Plass —
  Phil Klass
- Asa Akimisov —
  Isaac Asimov
- Ned Burgeon, wearing a sky-blue dinner jacket and a pepper-and-salt goatee, played his famous twenty-one-string guitar —
  Ted Sturgeon?
- L. Vague Duchamp —
  L. Sprague de Camp
- Larry Bagsby
- Diarrhetics —
  Dianetics
- H. Drene Pfeiffer —
  H. Beam Piper
- B. U. Jadrys —
  Algis (A. J.) Budrys
- Will Kubatius
- the heldentenor bulk of Don W. Gamble, Jr. —
  John W. Campbell?
- Kosmo Samwitz —
  Sam Moskowitz
- Don Bierce
- Lobbard discovering Scatiology —
  L. Ron Hubbard, and Scientology
- Werner Kley —
  Willy Ley
- Fred Balester
- M. C. (Hotfoot) Burncloth
- Ham Jibless' homemade telescope

Comment: Note that most of these, rather than parodies, appear to be _anagrams_. Some of them are deliberately funny anagrams, but mostly they're just anything that looks like a name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Larry Shaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Shaw_(editor)) wrote an article about this story in the fanzine [*Fan History* #3](https://www.fanac.org/fanzines/Fanhistory/Fanhistory03.pdf) (April 1, 1956). His assignments were as follows (see page 12). Anagrams (and near-anagrams) are marked with †.

| Character | Represents |
| --- | --- |
| Rod Pfehl† | [Fred Pohl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederik_Pohl) |
| Tom Q. Jones | [George O. Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_O._Smith) |
| Punchy Carrol<sup>1</sup> | [Judy Merril](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judith_Merril) |
| Leigh MacKean | [Kay MacLean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katherine_MacLean) |
| Dorrance Canning | [Laurence Manning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurence_Manning) |
| Art Gerymbergen† | [Marty Greenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Greenberg) |
| Bill Plass | [Phil Klass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Tenn)<sup>2</sup> |
| Asa Akimisov† | [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov) |
| Ned Burgeon | [Ted Sturgeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Sturgeon) |
| L. Vague Duchamp<sup>3</sup> | [L. Sprague De Camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._Sprague_de_Camp) |
| B. U. Jadrys†<sup>4</sup> | [A. J. Budrys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algis_Budrys) |
| Larry Bagsby | [Jerry Bixby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerome_Bixby) |
| Ray Alvarez | [Lester del Rey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lester_del_Rey) |
| H. Drene Pfeiffer | [H. Beam Piper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._Beam_Piper) |
| Will Kubatius† | [Walter Kubilius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Kubilius) |
| Don W. Gamble, Jr. | [John W. Campbell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_W._Campbell) |
| Horty Plass | Morty Klass<sup>5</sup> |
| Jerry Thaw | [Larry Shaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Shaw_(editor)) |
| Preacher Flatt | [Fletcher Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher_Pratt) |
| Kosmo Samwitz† | [Sam Moskowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Moskowitz) |
| Don Bierce | [John Pierce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_R._Pierce) |
| Balmer | [Raymond A.] [Palmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_A._Palmer) |
| Phog Relapse | [Rog Phillips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rog_Phillips) |
| Werner Kley | [Willy Ley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willy_Ley) |
| Fred Balester† | [Alfred Bester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Bester) |
| M. C. (Hotfoot) Burncloth† | [C. M. (Hotfoot) Kornbluth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyril_M._Kornbluth)<sup>6</sup> |
| Ham Jibless† | [James Blish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Blish) |

Notes:

1. An allusion to the folk characters [Punch and Judy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punch_and_Judy).
2. Better known by his pseudonym [William Tenn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Tenn).
3. Possibly an allusion to the artist [Marcel Duchamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_Duchamp), as suggested in the other answer.
4. "B.U." was 1930s slang, standing for "biological urge" and meaning "sexual attraction" (see [*New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*, p. 275](https://archive.org/details/newpartridgedict00tomd_0/page/275/mode/2up)). It's hard to tell whether this was intentional or an accident of the anagram, but Shaw does say that Knight was fond of sneaking risqué jokes into his stories.
5. Mort Klass, the younger brother of Phil Klass (see Damon Knight's [*The Futurians*, p. 185](https://archive.org/details/futurians0000knig/page/184/mode/2up)).
6. A "hotfoot" is "a prank in which a matchbook is lit and inserted into an unsuspecting victim's shoe" ([*New Partridge Dictionary*, p. 1038](https://archive.org/details/newpartridgedict00tomd_0/page/1037/mode/2up)). Kornbluth's propensity for the prank is indicated by an incident where "At the [1940 Chicago science fiction] convention Bob Tucker paid a 1¢ bribe to Kornbluth in order to escape being given a hotfoot" ([*The Futurians*, p. 83](https://archive.org/details/futurians0000knig/page/82/mode/2up), spotted by eac2222 in comments).

Shaw also commented:

> … plus a ubiquitous fan known as Harry Somebody; many people have taken the model for him to be Harlan Ellison, but I'm sure it was actually Joe Fann that damon had in mind.
>
> (I honestly don't know just how Joycean damon was being in some of these cases. Ham Jibless is a lovely anagram of James Blish, but it could be even more than that: Ham Brooks, in the old Doc Savage stories, was a dapper character who carried a sword-cane; James Blish is a dapper character who used to carry an umbrella-cane.)

I guess the joke in "ubiquitous fan, Harry *You*-Know", is that Joe Fann was a fan by name as well as by nature.

It's not mentioned in Shaw's article, but the "Medusa Club" of the story represented the [Hydra Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydra_Club), many of whose members appeared in this group caricature by [Harry Harrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Harrison_(writer)), published in *Marvel Science Fiction*, November 1951.

[image]

Comment: Great! It had occurred to me that someone might have published a key to this story in a fanzine, but I didn't know how to look for it. How did you find it?

Comment: "M. C. (Hotfoot) Burncloth" for Kornbluth may refer to the incident in Knight's _The Futurians_ where ". . . Bob Tucker paid a 1 cent bribe to Kornbluth in order to escape being given a hotfoot" (page 83).

Comment: @user14111 Nothing clever! I did a Google search for one of the names from the story, I think it might have been "punchy carrol", and *Fan History* #3 showed up on the first page of results.

Answer (score 15):

Preacher Flatt — [Fletcher Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher_Pratt)

Ray Alvarez — [Lester del Rey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lester_del_Rey#Birth_name)

Rod Pfehl (the P is silent, as in Psmith) — [Fred Pohl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederik_Pohl)

Tom Q. Jones went by in a hurry, carrying a big camera. —

Punchy Carrol, nut-brown in a red dress — Possibly [Carol Emshwiller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carol_Emshwiller#Bibliography)? She was writing in the 1950s.

Duchamp biting his pipe — If this is a different Duchamp than the one referencing L. Sprague de Camp, then it is almost certainly [Marcel Duchamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_Duchamp), but [it wasn't really a pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images).

Leigh MacKean with her pale protoNordic face — [Leigh Brackett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leigh_Brackett)

the ubiquitous fan, Harry You-Know, the one with the glasses and all that hair — likely [Harlan Ellison](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harlan_Ellison), whose [antics as a fan in the 1950s](https://fancyclopedia.org/Harlan_Ellison) are the stuff of legend.

Dorrance Canning, an old idol of mine; he wrote the "Woman Who Slept" series and other gorgeous stuff – The "Woman Who Slept" is a reference to [The Man Who Awoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Awoke). — [Laurence Manning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurence_Manning)

Art Greymbergen, my favorite publisher — [Martin Greenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Greenberg)

Bill Plass — [Phil Klass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Tenn) (a.k.a. William Tenn)

Asa Akimisov — [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov)

Ned Burgeon, wearing a sky-blue dinner jacket and a pepper-and-salt goatee, played his famous twenty-one-string guitar — [Ted Sturgeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Sturgeon) who did indeed wear a salt and pepper goatee at some point

L. Vague Duchamp — [L. Sprague de Camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._Sprague_de_Camp)

Larry Bagsby — [Jerome ("Jerry") Bixby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerome_Bixby)

Diarrhetics — [Dianetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dianetics) (authored by [L. Ron Hubbard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._Ron_Hubbard))

H. Drene Pfeiffer — [H. Beam Piper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._Beam_Piper)

B. U. Jadrys — [A. J. "Algis" Budrys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algis_Budrys)

Will Kubatius — [Walter Kubilius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Kubilius)

the heldentenor bulk of Don W. Gamble, Jr. — [John W. Campbell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_W._Campbell), who also wrote under the name "Don A. Stuart."

Kosmo Samwitz — [Sam Moskowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Moskowitz)

Don Bierce — [John Pierce](https://www.pbs.org/transistor/album1/pierce/index.html), inventor of the transistor, and an author of science fiction under the pseudonym of [J. J. Coupling](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?John_R._Pierce).

Lobbard discovering Scatiology — [L. Ron Hubbard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._Ron_Hubbard), and [Scientology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_Scientology)

Werner Kley — [Willy Ley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willy_Ley)

Fred Balester — [Alfred Bester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Bester)

M. C. (Hotfoot) Burncloth — [C. [Cyril] M. Kornbluth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyril_M._Kornbluth)

Ham Jibless' homemade telescope — [James Blish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Blish)

Balmer — [Ray Palmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_A._Palmer)

Phog Relapse — [Rog Phillips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rog_Phillips)

Jerry Thaw —

Comment: This has (like the question) Duchamp twice.

Comment: @SQB I think it might be reasonable that they are different Duchamps? I have made a clarifying edit to the possible Marcel Duchamp answer based on your input.

Comment: The Treachery of Images was actually by Magritte, not DeChamp.

Comment: Tom Q. Jones = Raymond F. Jones?

Comment: Since most of these are anagrams, I suspect the double-r in "Punchy Carrol" is no accident. One name you can get from that is "Charly", leaving "puncro" to make a surname. "Paul" is also in there, but that leaves you "nchycrro", which looks less likely.